# Creating custom tags

Tags: tags

Hi there Best Wordpress Gurus,

i've a question about using tags to simplify my HTML. For example if i want to ad a block of content lets say a contact form. I don't want to ad all the time my html code can i use a tag something like:

`#contact_form` and that this tag output a contactform for me.

If this possible can someone please give me a link to tutorial or gives a example.

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navid,

There is functionality which will for the most part accomplish what you are looking for.  In WordPress you can create what are known as shortcodes.  These, when inserted into a post or page, will allow you to display complex information, much like using a macro  Shortcodes can be used for very simple or more complex tasks.  Here are some articles to help you get started.

[Wordpress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

[Wp Tuts+ Shortcode Article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/wordpress-shortcodes-the-right-way/)

Comment: Hi mitchell thank you very much for your help. i'll check the links.